# White test with neural networks in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, heteroscedasticity

I'm trying to apply the White test for heteroskedasticity to some neural network models in Python (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_white.html). The built-in White test of the *statsmodels* package seems to assume that the (exogeneous) variables also contain the bias term, since for some reason the OLS fitting procedure does not include an intercept term by default.

However, for more complex models, such as neural networks, I have no idea what to do here. (Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72188315/how-to-perform-het-white-without-constant)

Right now I can circumvent the assertion error checking the number of degrees of freedom by simply adding a column of ones, as with statsmodels' *add_constant* method. But since this is a more complicated setting, I was wondering if this is correct?

Comment: I am not even sure how the underlying concept of the White test (variance of errors depending on regressors) would apply to a nonparametric technique like a neural network. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This was indeed also a question I have been asking myself. In theory, I think, the test should apply to any regression model, but it is hard to find anything on the topic.